# SQL INNER JOIN returning more rows than I need

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my situation:

I have 2 tables, **tickets** and **tickets-details**. I need to retrieve the info inside **"tickets"** and just the LAST reply from **"tickets-details"** for each ticket, then show em in a table. My problem is that **"ticket-details"** returns a row per each reply and I'm getting more than one row per ticket. How can I achieve this in a single query ?

I tried adding `DISTINCT` into my `SELECT` but didn't.

I tried using `GROUP BY` **id_ticket** but didnt' work too because I wasn't getting the last reply from ticket-details

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ti.id_ticket,ti.title,tiD.Reply,ti.status 
FROM tickets ti 
INNER JOIN ticket-details tiD ON ti.id_ticket = tiD.id_ticket 
WHERE user = '$id_user' ORDER BY status desc
```

---------------------------------- EDIT-----------------------------------------------

my tables:

tickets(**id_ticket**, user, date, title, status)

ticket-details(**id_ticketDetail**, id_ticket, dateReply, reply)

Comment: Does your `ticket-details` table have a timestamp column?

Comment: What do you mean by 'LAST reply'? Where is a date column in tickets-details table?

Comment: Your current query doesn't look valid: `ticket-details` is not a valid unquoted identifier.

Comment: Can you put your table schema up for us please?

Comment: Agreed -- the question is, what is the criteria for choosing which record to show from `ticket-details`?

Comment: Ok, I already put my tables. What I need from ticket-details is the last reply done. Yes it has a timestamp (dateReply) @SOfanatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know Your datatabase model, but if ID is autoincremented you can extend your script with this condition:

```
SELECT ti.id_ticket,ti.title,tiD.Reply,ti.status 
FROM tickets ti 
 INNER JOIN ticket-details tiD ON ti.id_ticket = tiD.id_ticket 
WHERE user = '$id_user' 
 and tiD.id_ticket in (select max(a.id) from ticket-details a group by a.id_ticket)
ORDER BY status desc
```

Or if you have some kind of date attribute, change new condition to your date attribute (in my example it is ticked_date )

```
and tiD.ticked_date in (select max(a.ticked_date) from ticket-details a group by a.id_ticket)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the max `id_ticketDetail` represents the most recent record in `ticket-details` you can try

```
SELECT ti.id_ticket,
       ti.title,
       tiD.Reply,
       ti.status 
  FROM tickets ti JOIN 
(
    SELECT id_ticket, reply
      FROM `ticket-details` d JOIN 
    ( 
        SELECT MAX(id_ticketDetail) max_id
          FROM `ticket-details`
         GROUP BY id_ticket
    ) q ON d.id_ticketDetail = q.max_id
) tiD ON ti.id_ticket = tiD.id_ticket 
 WHERE ti.user = '$id_user' 
 ORDER BY ti.status DESC
```

or a version with max `dateReply`

```
SELECT ti.id_ticket,
       ti.title,
       tiD.Reply,
       ti.status 
  FROM tickets ti JOIN 
(
    SELECT d.id_ticket, d.reply
      FROM `ticket-details` d JOIN 
    ( 
        SELECT id_ticket, MAX(dateReply) max_dateReply
          FROM `ticket-details`
         GROUP BY id_ticket
    ) q ON d.id_ticket = q.id_ticket
       AND d.dateReply = q.max_dateReply
) tiD ON ti.id_ticket = tiD.id_ticket 
 WHERE ti.user = '$id_user' 
 ORDER BY ti.status DESC
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5664/4)** demo for both queries.

Comment: In this answer, the tiD alias does not have the column Reply, so I don't think this query will even execute.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I tried your first answer but it did the same that my query does.

Comment: @user2088447 It was a typo in a name of id field. I've updated answer.

Comment: Your second answer works :) thanks for your time. Sorry but someone else got the answer first. Anyways I upvote your answer. Good luck

Comment: @user2088447 You're very welcome :) You can check a sqlfiddle demo that I provided for both queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to grab a bunch of tickets with their ticket-details, adding a subquery would work (though it's a little inefficient):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ti.id_ticket,ti.title,tiD.Reply,ti.status 
FROM tickets ti INNER JOIN ticket-details tiD 
    ON ti.id_ticket = tiD.id_ticket 
WHERE user = '$id_user' AND 
    tiD = (select id from ticket-details where ticket-details.id_ticket = ti.id_ticket ORDER BY ticket-details.date_field DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY status desc
```

If you only need to do this for one ticket at a time, it's as simple as ordering by the date field in ticket-details and throwing a limit in there:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ti.id_ticket,ti.title,tiD.Reply,ti.status 
FROM tickets ti INNER JOIN ticket-details tiD 
    ON ti.id_ticket = tiD.id_ticket 
WHERE user = '$id_user' ORDER BY tiD.date_field, status DESC LIMIT 1
```